# document.body is null when using from a content script in my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm observing an interesting behavior that I don't fully understand. I'm injecting the `content script` for my Chrome Extension into every page that is loaded in the Chrome web browser. The `manifest.json` filter for that is set up as such:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames" : true,
        "match_about_blank": true,
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
```

I then attempt to add `onClick` global event to the whole loaded document from my `content.js`:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', onClickOnPage, true);

function onClickOnPage(evnt)
{
    //process global onClick on the page
}
```

The method above seems to work, except in some rare occasions I get the following exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

What is causing it?

Comment: Debugging: does it change if you put it in a 1-second `setTimeout`?

Comment: @phatskat: I didn't try. But why would I want to do that?

Comment: You said "rare cases" - is it just random or the same pages? If it's random, it may be that document.body simply doesn't exist yet?

Comment: @phatskat: Well, yeah, since it's 'null'. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to try and wrap your code in `DOMContentLoaded` listener.

Comment: @Xan: I tried and I don't think it's called at all.

Comment: Please define "in some rare occasions". Is the problem deterministic?

Comment: @c00000fd without the context of "rare occasions," the best I can tell you is that your script is hitting before the browser has created the document.body object. Especially in Chrome, `<body>` should exist at some point, but your script seems to be getting invoked before that.

Comment: @RobW: No, it is not `deterministic`.